# How do you evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{\sin^2{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can you work out this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^{\sin^2{x}}$$

I have tried several methods,but nothing worked. Could you use L'Hopital somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use $x = e^{\log x}$ ans as $x \to 0$, $\sin x \approx x$, and you know $x \log x \to 0$
$$\exp \left ({x \frac{\log x}{\frac 1x}} \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\right)$$
Use L'Hopital on $\frac{\log x}{\frac 1x}$ rest is okay.

Comment: Can you actually do that? It seems wrong to me .

Comment: @Bardo what do you seem to think wrong?

Comment: The approximation. I am not sure that we can actually do that, that is approximating functions while taking limits.

Comment: @bardo you can do that without approximating

Comment: Ok, now I have no doubt! thank you

Answer (score 3):

$y = x^{\sin^2x}$ so  $y= e^{~\!\sin^2x\ln x}$  and $\sin x \approx x$ so $\ y \approx \ e^{x^2  \ln x}$ so $\lim_{x\to 0} y$ equals to $e^0$  so the answer is 1  (we know $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 \ln x $ is 0)

Comment: It doesn't equal e^0, because you have $e^{x^2\ln{x}}$ and when x tends to 0 you get $ e^{0\ln0} = e^{0(-\infty)}$ which is undetermined

Comment: Sorry, now I agree with tou! Thank you!